# ASP.NET WebAPI 2: handle empty string query parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

We have an api used to get data of products:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProducts(ProductFilter productFilter)
{
    try
    {
        .....
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        throw new OurCustomException();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ProductFilter
{
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}$")]
    public String Number { get; set; }
    .....
}
```

Here is what i want:

1. When send `GET /api/products?number=Test1234567` it will return information of a product with the number "Test1234567"
2. When send `GET /api/products?number=` it will return error because the empty string does not match the regex
3. When send `GET /api/products` it will return information of all products

So can you suggest me any way to do this by using just Validation Attribute, since we have a common method to handle `ValidationException` and we cannot throw `ValidationException` from method `GetProducts`. I have tried to use `[Required]` and `[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]` on `Number` but none of them worked.

And please also inform me if it is impossible.

Comment: Side note: Your api call should really not be throwing exceptions but returning Http status codes like 400 or 500 if it fails. There are built in methods to do this like `BadRequest(string)`, `Conflict()`, `InternalServerError`, etc.

Comment: Refer to this article on how to do model validation using Web API: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api. It seems like you are missing some code that actually validates the model.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I think your problem is that you are not passing full model as parameter - your are getting `null` once binder tries to bind query string. This is not a problem with your regex. To get it working you should make q request like `GET /api/products?number=&prop1=some_value&prop2=some_value`

---

Original answer:

I think changing your regex to:

```
public class ProductFilter
{
    [RegularExpression(@"^(|[a-zA-Z0-9]{11})$")]
    public String Number { get; set; }
    .....
}
```

should do a trick.

However MSDN documentation states that:

> If the value of the property is null or an empty string (""), the
>   value automatically passes validation for the
>   RegularExpressionAttribute attribute.

So it should work anyway. Additionally we can check `RegularExpression` code:

```
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
      this.SetupRegex();
      string input = Convert.ToString(value, (IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        return true;
      Match match = this.Regex.Match(input);
      if (match.Success && match.Index == 0)
        return match.Length == input.Length;
      return false;
    }
```

as you can see, it allows null or empty input so your problem is rather different.